# User Defined Function returning wrong values when passing a Data Frame as argument

Tags: r, user-defined-functions, dplyr

I have a function to make interpolations that goes as below:

```
interpola <- function(DF, vlBase, interpolY = TRUE) {
  DataFrameInterpol <- data.frame(DF)
  FunctionVlBase <- as.numeric(vlBase)
  InterpolaVar <- interpolY

  if (InterpolaVar) n <- 1 else n <- 2

  df1 <- filter(data.frame(DataFrameInterpol),
                data.frame(DataFrameInterpol[, n]) <= FunctionVlBase) %>% top_n(1)
  x1 <- df1[, 1]
  y1 <- df1[, 2]

  df2 <- filter(data.frame(DataFrameInterpol),
                data.frame(DataFrameInterpol[, n]) >= FunctionVlBase) %>% top_n(-1)
  x2 <- df2[, 1]
  y2 <- df2[, 2]

  # Se interpolY == TRUE
  # Retorna Y
  if (InterpolaVar) {
    # Checa se vlBase está na DF
    if (x1 == x2) {
      return(y1)
    }
    else {
      tmp <- (FunctionVlBase - x1) * (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1) + y1
      return(tmp)
    }
  }

  # Se interpolY <> TRUE
  # Retorna X
  else if (!InterpolaVar) {
    # Checa se vlBase está na DF
    if (y1 == y2) {
      return(x1)
    }
    else {
      tmp <- (FunctionVlBase - y1) * (x2 - x1) / (y2 - y1) + x1
      return(tmp)
    }
  }
}
```

The function receives a DataFrame with 2 columns (x,y) that are the base values for the interpolation, a value to be used as the point that i want to interpolate and a boolean argument to define if i the interpolation should made under the x or y access.

The function works fine when the vlBase is a numeric argument but when i try to pass a DataFrame column (e.g. `mutate(BaseDate, interpola(InterpolaDF, BaseData$Values))`) it gives me wrong results.

I have the following DataFrames:
InterpolaDF

```
BusinessDaysToMat RateAcum
0 1.000246
6 1.001476
29 1.007173
48 1.011959
70 1.017700
90 1.023123
```

DateVector:

```
Date    Refdate BusinessDaysToMat
2018-07-24 2018-07-24                 0
2018-07-25 2018-07-24                 1
2018-07-26 2018-07-24                 2
2018-07-27 2018-07-24                 3
2018-07-28 2018-07-24                 3
2018-07-29 2018-07-24                 3
2018-07-30 2018-07-24                 4
2018-07-31 2018-07-24                 5
2018-08-01 2018-07-24                 6
2018-08-02 2018-07-24                 7
2018-08-03 2018-07-24                 8
2018-08-04 2018-07-24                 8
2018-08-05 2018-07-24                 8
2018-08-06 2018-07-24                 9
2018-08-07 2018-07-24                10
```

If I execute something like `interpola(InterpolaDF, 22)` i get 1.002467 (which is the expected return), but if do `interpola(InterpolaDF, dateVector$BusinessDaysToMat)` on the row that has BusinessDaysToMat = 10 I get the return of 1.000246

Comment: can you provide a sample `dput(df)` output of your data ?

Comment: One of your first lines is `DataFrameInterpol <- data.frame(DF)`. From that point forward, `DataFrameInterpol` is a data frame, so don't wrap it in `data.frame()` when you use it. It's already a data frame.

Comment: @YOLO:
I have the following DataFrames:
InterpolaDF: 
BusinessDaysToMat RateAcum
0 1.000246
6 1.001476
29 1.007173
48 1.011959
dateVector:

Date    BusinessDaysToMat
2018-07-24 0
2018-07-25 1
2018-07-26 2
2018-07-27 3
2018-07-28 3
2018-07-29 3
2018-07-30 4
2018-07-31 5
...

If i execute something like interpola(InterpolaDF, 47) i get 1.011707 (wich is the expected return), but if do interpola(InterpolaDF, dateVector$BusinessDaysToMat) on the row that has BusinessDaysToMat = 47 i have the return of 1.000246.

Comment: @Gregor
Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Please include your sample data in the question, don't bury it in a comment.

Comment: @Gregor Done. Thanks again !